# Relevance of a sequence in determinants of a matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant

There is a matrix which posses properties of pascal triangle and it has an additional property of its determinants when calculated occur in a particular sequence. Is there any application of this in any field. Is it of any use to mathematics world?

Comment: What **exactly** is this matrix you speak of?

Comment: I cannot disclose that due to confidentiality.